# Unable to show a message after plugin activation

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, activation

Based on: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices

My actual code

```
class Activation {

  function __construct() {

    add_action( 
      'admin_notices', 
      array($this,"text_admin_notices")
    );

    Utils::update_option("is_activated", true);
  }

  function text_admin_notices () {
    ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p> TEST MESSAGE</p>
        </div
    <?php
  }

}
```

I know that `__construct()` is being executed, because `Utils::update_option` (a simple wrapper) is working, it's creating the option in the option table.

So I expect that the call to `add_action` should show a message to the admin user that is activating my plugin.

Actually, the plugin is beign activated, but no message is shown.

I'm using Wordpress 4.7.1 (a fresh, clean, no-other-stuff, today's installation)

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Activation
  Description: This display notice message test plugin
  Author: Nanhe Kumar
  Version: 1.0
  Author URI: http://nanhe.in/
 */

class Activation {

    public static function init() {
        add_action('admin_notices', array(__CLASS__, 'text_admin_notice'));
    }

    public static function text_admin_notice() {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p> TEST MESSAGE</p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

}
add_action('init', array('Activation', 'init'));
```

Your message not showing because your class constructor is not executing you can test through add die in your constructor then you can better understand what is happening.

Comment: I already tested AND my constructor is being executed regularry.

Comment: @realtebo : Ok can you share complete code